# Dar la vuelta a una cadena en C

Tags: c, string

estoy intentando darle vuelta a una cadena pero me dice que mi funcion (la que escribí para darle la vuelta) pero me dice que el return me devuelve un interger de un puntero sin un cast, y no entiendo porque, os dejo el código:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define kmax 15

typedef char tcad[kmax];

char reves(tcad);

int main()
{
    tcad array;
    char reverse;
    printf("Introduce una palabra de máximo 15 letras: ");
    scanf("%s", array);
    printf("Tus caracteres son: %s\n", array);
    reverse = reves(array);
    printf("%c",reverse);
}
    
char reves (tcad ar)
{
    int len = strlen(ar);
    int left, right;
    char temp;
    for(left = 0, right = len-1;left<(len/2);left++,right--)
    {
        temp = ar[left];
        ar[left] = ar[right];
        ar[right] = temp;
    }
    return(ar);
}
```

Gracias

Comment: Tienes un `return(ar)` y `ar` es de tipo array de caracteres. En cambio tu función declara retonar un `char`. De ahi el error. Realmente no necesitas retornar nada (puedes hacer que el tipo retornado sea `void` y acabar con un simple `return`) pues la función modifica la cadena "directamente en el sitio" (es decir, en el array que recibe como parámetro). Desde main tienes que imprimir `array` en lugar del valor retornado (y usar `%s` en vez de `%c`)

Comment: SI, al final lo pude solucionar cambiándolo a un void, gracias :)